# WSS headers in SOAP request for java client

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I am consuming a SOAP based webservice in a Java. I tested the webservice in SOAP UI, tried to send the request and I successfully got the response. The request is working only if I manually add the security  *wsse:Security* and send the valid username and password. Only then I am getting a valid response.

Right now I want to send the request through a simple JAVA code, get a response.

I used wsimport to create the stub files.

I don't see any java files generated for setting the username & password. **How do we need to set the username & password and pass on to the request ??**

Will there be any different in consuming a secured() service to non-sercured ()??

Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't see the web service security related tags (i.e `wsse:Security`etc.) in your stubs due your stubs are the beans for your `xsd` schema and `WSS` is a standard which has it's own tags defined in a specific `xsd` (It's like for example `soap`, you can send your request inside a `<soap:envelope>` however this related tags are not in your stubs).

To add the `WSS` features to your java client you can use [apache `WSS4J`](https://ws.apache.org/wss4j/). In order to add a username and password as you ask in the question, you can do it using the following code:

```
WSSecUsernameToken builder = new WSSecUsernameToken();
builder.setPasswordType(WSConstants.PASSWORD_TEXT);
// set user name an password
builder.setUserInfo("wernerd", "verySecret");
// create a sample soap message
Document doc = SOAPUtil.toSOAPPart(SOAPUtil.SAMPLE_SOAP_MSG);
WSSecHeader secHeader = new WSSecHeader(doc);
secHeader.insertSecurityHeader();
// create the soap message with WSS headers
Document signedDoc = builder.build(doc, secHeader);
// simply print the result
System.out.println(XMLUtils.prettyDocumentToString(signedDoc));
```

This snippet is extracted from *Junit* tests of the apache `WSS4J` project. You can check `testUsernameTokenText()` method on `UserNameTokenTest` class on [apache `WSS4J` svn repository](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/webservices/wss4j/trunk/ws-security-dom/src/test/java/org/apache/wss4j/dom/message/UsernameTokenTest.java?view=markup)

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks @albciff. I was able to pass the header & security through request handler & SOAPMessage. Now I am able to generate the xml request.

Comment: @Venkat perfect `:)`.